# Диалог пропускает вопрос Python (Отлично, напомни, когда у тебя день рождения? (день(буквами) месяц))

Tags: python

```
hello = input("Привет ")
if hello == "привет":
hello = input("Я ищу xx, знаешь такого? ")
else:
print("Почему бы просто не поздороваться? ")
if hello == "да":
hello = input("Отлично, это ты? ")
else:
print("Тогда вызовешь меня, когда он придёт! ")
if hello == "да":
print('Отлично, напомни, когда у тебя день рождения? (день(буквами) месяц) ')
elif "нет":
print("Тогда вызовешь меня, когда он придёт!")
if hello == "xx":
print(
    "Поздравляю тебя с днём рождения, братик! Желаю тебе в этот День Рождения здоровья, 
которого хватило бы"
    " на долгие годы, мощной энергии и нескончаемой силы. В душе будь всегда молодым, никогда 
не опускай руки, "
    "будь весёлым, позитивным и радуйся веселым моментам жизни. Я Люблю Тебя! "
    "P.S Звони по чаще маме и про меня не забывай :)")
else:
print("Ты не знаешь день своего рождения!? Ты шутишь?")
if hello == "Да":
print(
    "Поздравляю тебя с днём рождения, братик! Желаю тебе в этот День Рождения здоровья, 
которого хватило бы"
    " на долгие годы, мощной энергии и нескончаемой силы. В душе будь всегда молодым, никогда 
не опускай руки, "
    "будь весёлым, позитивным и радуйся веселым моментам жизни. Я Люблю Тебя! "
    "P.S Звони по чаще маме и про меня не забывай :)")
elif "нет":
print("Ну ладно..."
      "Сегодня же ТВОЙ день рождения!!!"
      "Поздравляю тебя с днём рождения, братик! Желаю тебе в этот День Рождения здоровья, 
которого хватило бы"
      " на долгие годы, мощной энергии и нескончаемой силы. В душе будь всегда молодым, 
никогда не опускай руки, "
      "будь весёлым, позитивным и радуйся веселым моментам жизни. Я Люблю Тебя! "
      "P.S Звони по чаще маме и про меня не забывай :)")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что у Вас с отступами?

Answer (score -1):

Еще дело в отступах там где if , они должны быть так как вылетает ошибка не забывай про отступы и так же там где else: если на нем есть условие то тогда else hello == (что-то):

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Отсутствие отступов  - плод неправильного копирования кода